# Can't install WineHQ on Ubuntu: doesn't support architecture '1386'

Tags: wine, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu, and trying to install WineHQ using the instructions on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu . I first tried it on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and then again after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. The results are the same regardless.

The first step is ensure that 32-bit architecture is enabled, and it seems it is. Next step is to download and add the repository key. So far so good.

```
tb@tb-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
tb@tb-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
tb@tb-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
File ‘winehq.key’ already there; not retrieving.

tb@tb-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key
[sudo] password for tb: 
OK
```

This is where I run into trouble. Since I'm now on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, I add the repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

...and I get the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]        
Hit:5 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease              
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:7 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Fetched 114 kB in 1s (111 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-1386/Packages' as repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' doesn't support architecture '1386'
```

" doesn't support architecture '1386' " seems to imply that the error has something to do with 32-bit vs 64-bit architecture, but I already took steps to ensure that it's set up correctly, so I don't understand what's going wrong.
What am I missing and how do I fix it?

I googled the error but can't find anything that's simple enough for me to understand.

Best regards, A non-coder who needs one Windows application for work

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*wine*.list` file created by the `add-apt-repository` command?

Comment: bash: cd: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*wine*.list: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to install a version of wine other than that already found in the 20.04 Ubuntu repos?

Comment: Sorry, what? As far as I can tell, wine is not already installed in Ubuntu 20.04, and I'm following the official instructions for installing WineHQ for Ubuntu 20.04. So I'm not sure what you mean. I'd be happy to abandon this project if there's an easier way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: It's not already installed, but it is available in the Ubuntu repositories. The page you linked to shows how to add a third party repository. It mentions differences between "distro" packages (that is, ones in Ubuntu repos) and the packages in the third party repo it shows how to add.  Without adding the new repository, if I run `apt search wine` on my 20.04 system, I see numerous wine related packages that can be installed with `sudo apt install <package-name>` without any extra steps. People may choose to add third party repos to get more up to date software, for example.

Comment: Oh, so the linked website is for Wine 6, but Wine 5 can be installed with `sudo apt install wine64 wine32` . I had no idea. Still working on getting it to work, but I don't think I need version 6, so it looks promising. Many thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 4):

There is no such architecture as `1386`. It seems it might be a typo of `i386`.

You can try running

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
```

and then run `sudo apt update` again.